# Lua - How do I sort all files found (via LFS) alphabetically?

Tags: lua

Please could someone help me finish my function that can sort all the filenames I’ve pulled via Lua File System, as I can’t seem to do it? Code is below. (All help would be appreciated)

```
local lfs = require "lfs" 
local json = require("json")
local tt = {}

function browseFolder(root)
    for entity in lfs.dir(root) do
        if entity~="." and entity~=".." then
        
            local fullPath=root..'/'..entity
            local mode=lfs.attributes(fullPath,"mode")
            if mode=="file" and entity: match "%.mkv$" then
            
                table.insert(tt, { 
                    filename = entity,
                    folder = root})
                
            elseif mode=="directory" then
                
                browseFolder(fullPath);
            end
        end
    end
end

browseFolder(".")

--print(tt)

table.sort(tt, function(a, b) return a:filename() < b:filename() end)
                
for k,d in ipairs(tt) do
    --print(d.filename)
    print(k, d.filename, d.folder)
--end   
end
```

And... if anyone knows of a way to do another function that includes extra file attributes too, such as file size, date created, etc. And then be able to sort via either one of those too,  that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `lfs.attributes` and full path to access the file:

```
local lfs = require "lfs" 
local json = require("json")
local tt = {}

function browseFolder(root)
    for entity in lfs.dir(root) do
        if entity~="." and entity~=".." then
        
            local fullPath=root..'/'..entity
            local mode=lfs.attributes(fullPath,"mode")
            if mode=="file" and entity: match "%.*$" then -- all files
            
                table.insert(tt, { 
                    filename = entity,
                    folder = root,
                    date_ch = lfs.attributes(root .. '//'.. entity, "change") 
                    })
                print(entity,root)
            elseif mode=="directory" then
                
                browseFolder(fullPath);
            end
        end
    end
end

browseFolder(".")


table.sort(tt, function(a, b) return a.date_ch < b.date_ch end) -- sort by date of change
                
for k,d in pairs(tt) do
    print(k, d.filename, os.date("%c",d.date_ch) , d.folder)
end
```

and instead `a:filename() < b:filename()`  use `a.filename < b.filename`